# Open Sketch files on Windows 10 and up

Tags: gratis, windows-10, sketch

I've got several `.sketch` files created on Mac OSX by a designer. Now I want to open them on my machine with Windows 10 Pro 64 bit. Alternatively I could also open them using an app in my Ubuntu 16.04 VM (via VirtualBox) if needed.

- **Must have**: can *view* `.sketch` files created on latest version of Sketch for OSX
- **Must have**: gratis
- **Must have**: software works on Windows 10 *or* Ubuntu
- **Should have**: software works on Windows 10
- **Nice to have**: ability to edit files
- **Nice to have**: printing (parts of) sketch files

Initial Google searches led me to "Icons8", but on their download page some *extremely* dodgy nsfw advertisements caused me to pause and ask for a recommendation here.

I also tried viewing the Sketch files straight in the Dropbox account (via Chrome) they were shared in, but that gave me a low-resolution mashup of all different screens in one big picture-like document, which wasn't very useful.

So I ask: what would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the proprietary native file format of [Sketch](https://www.sketchapp.com/), a program by Bohemian Coding that's only available for Mac OS. It's unlikely that anybody has put the work into reverse-engineering this format so you can open the files on some other operating system. It's a vector-graphics format, so ask your designer to export the file to a standard vector-graphics format like SVG, EPS, or PDF.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Not sure if it's that "unlikely" though because web searches turn up quite a few results. It's just that the main option seemed _sketchy_ and/or that I don't know which options would fit my requirements. (Leading me to ask the question.)